# PHP, vBulletin: Fatal error: Call to a member function clean_array_gpc() on a non-object

Tags: php, vbulletin

With vBulletin in PHP, I'm getting this error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function clean_array_gpc() on a non-object in C:\inetpub\forum\includes\class_bootstrap.php on line 124
```

on the following line of code:

```
    $vbulletin->input->clean_array_gpc('r', array(
        'referrerid' => TYPE_UINT,
        'a'          => TYPE_STR,
        'nojs'       => TYPE_BOOL
    ));
```

---

I can appreciate that either `$vbulletin` or `$vbulletin->input` hasn't been instantiated yet; but my question goes a bit deeper and is perhaps a bit vBulletin-centric:

- If not in `class_bootstrap.php`, where do `$vbulletin` (which, of course, is global) and `$vbulletin->input` get instantiated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens in `.\includes\class_core.php`.

In my particular installation, it occurs on line 3100 in the vB_Registry() function.

```
    function vB_Registry()
    {
        {...}

        // initialize the input handler
        $this->input = new vB_Input_Cleaner($this);

        {...}
     }
```